# admin-over-clients application

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture

I have the same web application running on several different servers. 
Now I want a central place to administer everything in one web interface. What is the best way to do this?

Should I provide a REST interface on every web application and let the admin application make all the calls?

This seems like a common problem that's already been solved by smarter people than me.

UPDATE: I want to change the application data per web application + see the results per web application

Comment: Administer what?  OS, users, application data?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about these applications its hard to make a recommendation.

That being said, generally I would try **centralize the Configuration information** and have the web servers go out and get it, Rather than to publish Configuration information out to the servers. (So I would never have to worry that the servers are out of sync.)